# How to perform join operation for following table?

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner programmer. Here are my table structures:

[image: Database structure]

I want to retrieve content and type field from 'post' table where userdId following the 'following' field. I am trying this SQL Join for retrive post of followers.

```
SELECT userId,following, userId,postId,content,file,type
FROM follow, post
WHERE userId = '5a37589e4ff8b'
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) syntax

```
SELECT f.userId, f.following, p.postId, p.content, p.file, p.type
    FROM follow f
    JOIN post p ON p.userId = f.userId
    WHERE f.userId = '5a37589e4ff8b'
```

Comment: should i replace f with follow and p with post ?

Comment: When you use `follow f` it's called an alias, it means that you can use it to prefix field names without having to use the full name.  So `f` becomes a shorthand for `follow`

Comment: thank you very much . one more thing can i tag you again if i get any trouble regarding this query ?

Comment: Just leave another message and I will try and help.  Not always around, but will always get back eventually.

Comment: thanks . Actually This query not gives me desired results .. i want to retrieve post of users which posted by followed users .

Comment: Do you mean `JOIN post p ON p.userId = f.following`?